# Why does my code filter out all the strings?

Tags: python-2.7

My code skips over some of the strings it seems.

```
def filter_list(l):
for i in l:
    if type(i) == str:
        l.remove(i)
return l

print filter_list([1, 2, 3, '4', '5', 6, '7', 8])
```

It outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, '5', 6, 8]
```

skipping over the '5' string

Comment: you are changing the list you are iterating over. this usually ends in tears. try a list-comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comment: you should not change a list while you are iterating over it (unless you *really* know what you are doing).

and [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) is usually safer to use than a `type` comparison.

with a [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) you could do this:

```
def filter_list(l):
    return [item for item in l if not isinstance(item, str)]

print(filter_list([1, 2, 3, '4', '5', 6, '7', 8]))  # [1, 2, 3, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

When execution flow encounters the first string `"4"` at position `3`, removes it and shifts all remaining items to the left so `"5"` will be at index `3`. But the next loop iteration comes to position `4`, so it skips `"5"`.

Consider the following approach using [***filter()***](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) function to perform a proper filtering process:

```
def filter_list(l):
    return list(filter(lambda i: not isinstance(i,str), l))

print filter_list([1, 2, 3, '4', '5', 6, '7', 8])
```

The output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing elements, while iterating, is slow and dangerous. The best choice is to create a new list `new_list = [x for x in l if not isinstance(x,str)]` . If list is really big, you can firstly find all elements that match the condition and after remove them

```
strings = [i for i,x in enumerate(l) if isinstance(x,str)]
for x in reversed(strings): 
    del l[x]
```

So the first choice (the fastest):

```
def filter_list(l):
    return [x for x in l if not isinstance(x, str)]

print(filter_list([1, 2, 3, '4', '5', 6, '7', 8]))
```

The second (if number of values to delete is small, but size of list is big):

```
def filter_list(l):
    strings = [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if isinstance(x, str)]
    for x in reversed(strings):
        del l[x]

l = [1, 2, 3, '4', '5', 6, '7', 8]
filter_list(l)
print(l)
```

Comment: So would
'code'def filter_list(l):
  indices = []
  for i in l:
      if type(i) != str:
          indices.append(i)
  return indices
'code'
work better?

Comment: how do i make the code go in code format in a comment?